# autocomplete não funciona após chamada ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tenho um campo de CEP com `autocomplete` que funciona perfeitamente quando digito algo. Porém esse campo também é preenchido após uma chamada ajax que preenche o CEP automaticamente, só que ao receber o valor (completo) da chamada o autocomplete não funciona.

Parte do meu autocomplete:

```
$('#PostalCode').autocomplete({
minLength: 9,
source: function(){
            var value = document.getElementById('PostalCode').value;
            var nameAction =  @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.ActionName));
            if (value !== null && value !== "") {
                $.ajax({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: "@Url.Action("getFullAddress", "DeliveryService")",
                    data: { postalCode: value, nameAction: nameAction },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#AddressStreet').val(data.AddressStreet);
                        $('#AddressNeighborhood').val(data.AddressNeighborhood);
                        $('#AddressCity').val(data.AddressCity);
                        $('#IdState').val(data.IdState);
                        $('#Latitude').val(data.Latitude);
                        $('#Longitude').val(data.Longitude);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        $('#AddressStreet').val("");
                        $('#AddressNeighborhood').val("");
                        $('#AddressCity').val("");
                        $('#AddressNumber').val("");
                        $('#AddressComplement').val("");
                        $('#IdState').val(""); 
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

O campo recebendo o valor após a chamada:

```
$('#PostalCode').val(result.PostalCode);
```

Queria disparar o `autocomplete` quando o campo recebe o valor da chamada AJAX.

**UPDATE**

Coloquei o código que faz a busca pelo CEP dentro de uma function `getCEP()`, ai consigo chamar ela após a chamada AJAX e dentro do  autoComplete, e pegar o valor do no campo usando o `getElementbyId`.

Comment: Estás a usar o `source:` do `autocomplete`? podes colocar o código do ajax?

Comment: editei a pergunta com o restante do codigo do autocomplete, ai funciona bem, só não dispara o `autocomplete` quando o campo `postalCode` recebe o cep completo de outra chamada